# Remove noise from image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I have these images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeFrG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ1mE.png)

I want to remove noise from these images so I can convert them into text using pytesseract. The noise is only in blue colour so I tried to remove blue from the image. Still not good results.

```
This is what I did
```

```
import cv2
import pytesseract



# Extract the blue channel
blue = img[:, :, 0]

# Apply thresholding to the blue channel
thresh = cv2.threshold(blue, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Perform morphological operations to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,1))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=7)

# Apply blur to smooth out the image
blur = opening#cv2.medianBlur(opening, 1)

cv2.imwrite("/Users/arjunmalik/Desktop/blur.png",blur)
display("/Users/arjunmalik/Desktop/blur.png")
```

The result was

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndjlm.png)

The OCR results were FL1S4y.

Comment: use a closing operator to reconstruct a bit the numbers you obtained https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Sembei, You need to use a closing operator which's a must for a situation like this because you want to close black points on the object to improve the image quality.

**Solution:**

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,4))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
```

You can modify your code to this one to achieve the following output for the second image.

**Output:**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjE8D.jpg)

You might need to change the size of the kernel for different input images.

**Thoughts:**

I think it'd be better if you do the character segmentation first before applying the closing operator in order to achieve the finest results.

Comment: It's still not working for only numbers